# CSS in servlets

Tags: javascript, html, css, servlets

I am using servlets. Now I have this in the head

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">  
   </script>
   <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {                        
                $('#navigation').load('Navigation');
            });
    </script>  
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

I have a navigation where I will put the result of the servlet in. It seems like that the CSS just counts for this HTML file and not for the HTML that is given through the servlet. Thats a problem, because I have a dropdown menu and that doesnt work if my CSS isn't considered. But my servlet does not have the head tag, of course. How can I make the CSS work for the HTML code of my servlet?

Comment: I don't know anything about servlets, but as long as you're generating valid HTML and you inject it into the DOM, the CSS will apply to it. The browser doesn't care if you load content after the page has been rendered, it will always update to display the new content with proper styles. It's a different story if you're using an iFrame, of course. If you provide an example link, I'll be able to have a look at the actual code and give you better guidance.

Comment: Post the HTML code that your Servlet returns. Does your returned HTML display in the browser? Make sure you do not have the `<body>` tag in the returned HTML as the DOM already has a body tag and your response is being added into it.